# file_get_content и json_encode php

Tags: php, json, json-encode, file-get-contents

Можете подсказать, почему подобный код (ниже), выводит такую ошибку `Warning:  Illegal string offset 'key'`

```
file.json:
[{
    'key': {
        0: {
            'key0': "data-0-0",
            'key1': "data-0-1"
        },
        1: {
            'key0': "data-1-0",
            'key1': "data-1-1"
        }
    }
}]

index.php:
$json = json_encode( file_get_contents( 'file.json' ) );
var_dump ( $json['key'] );
```

В файле, `file.json` нет никаких дополнительных символов.

Comment: Разве в `JSON` позволено использовать одинарные кавычки?

Comment: Выводиться в любом случаи в виде строки .. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причины аж сразу три. И ни одна не имеет никакого отношения к `file_get_contents`

Первая: представленный `file.json` вы называете `JSON` по какому-то заблуждению. Он нарушает [соответствующий RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) используя одинарные кавычки для строковых значений имён свойств. Затем, ключи `0:` не могут быть так записаны, это должен быть или массив объявленный через использование квадратных скобок либо ключи должны быть взяты в кавычки как строки. Поэтому `json_decode` вовсе прочитать структуру не может.

Второе: потому что нет у вас в JSON на верхнем уровне объекта с ключом `key`. У вас есть массив из одного объекта, в котором есть свойство `key`.

И третья ошибка - вы вызываете `json_decode` без второго параметра. Соответственно у вас вообще никогда не получится массив с ассоциативными ключами: будет или массив с числовыми ключами или объект класса `stdClass` для массива и объекта JSON документа соответственно.

Вот в таком виде - смысл имеет:

```
$input = <<<JSON
[{
    "key": {
        "0": {
            "key0": "data-0-0",
            "key1": "data-0-1"
        },
        "1": {
            "key0": "data-1-0",
            "key1": "data-1-1"
        }
    }
}]
JSON;

$json = json_decode($input, true);
var_dump($json[0]['key']);
```

---

Отдельного вопроса заслуживает заявленная в заголовке ошибка `Warning:  Illegal string offset 'key'`. Её так получить вовсе не выйдет, ошибка связана с попыткой обращения к строке как массиву с символьным ключом. Например, если вы `json_decode` не делаете вовсе.

Итог в общем-то един, смотрите на то что получаете через тот же `var_dump` и анализируйте следующие необходимые шаги до нужных вам данных.